# Feral and untamed

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

> A recent creation, I'm built like a horse;
>   I'm feral and untamed, a wild beast, of course.
>   Free content licensing I do endorse,
>   A bug ran from home and now codes open source.

What am I?

Comment: No knowledge tag?

Comment: Aaand now there is. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I can't stop finding awesome answers to your riddle, and still I feel that I didn't find the true answer. I enjoyed this very much!

Comment: @Cashbee glad to hear it!

Comment: @jafe my second answer is not correct, is it?

Comment: @Cashbee It is. Although you haven't figured out the first half of the last line yet :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you maybe

> A wildebeest?

A recent creation, I'm built like a horse;

> Wildebeests look similar to horses. In german, wildebeest is called "Gnu", which is a recent creation (OS). IIRC the term gnu is sometimes also used in english  for the animal

I'm feral and untamed, a wild beast, of course.

> It sure is a wilde beest :)

Free content licensing I do endorse,

> GNU GPL is the most commonly used free software license according to wikipedia

A bug ran from home and now codes open source.

> GNU is open sourced. There is a GNU de**bug**ger

Comment: The last clue seems off but I can't find a better explanation. Feel free to edit if you know it.

Comment: Regarding the last clue... My first though was that it alludes to how the user mode portion of most Linux distributions is actually taken from GNU (hence "GNU/Linux"), but upon further reflection, I think this is instead alluding to the fact that GNU was meant to be an open source replacement for Unix. It's even named after it with the recursive acronym "**G**NU's **N**ot **U**nix". The "bug ran from home" part could also allude to the fact that Richard Stallman quit his job to work on GNU so that his employers couldn't claim ownership of it and/or the fact that GNU's kernel is still buggy.

Comment: Also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ks80McKhss

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> A virus?

A recent creation, I'm built like a horse;

> trojan horse <--> trojan virus. viruses are a recent creation too, at least the non-biological kind.

I'm feral and untamed, a wild beast, of course.

> Viruses are wild and can destroy software

Free content licensing I do endorse,

> Viruses are often 'free', because you don't pay to install them (they get installed without your knowledge). Malware is often free to make it more attractive.

A bug ran from home and now codes open source.

> Bug ran from home could be a virus released from it's creator?

Comment: "viruses are more common with free software" [citation-needed], unless you mean that malware is more often free. I read that as "free, legitimate software is more often compromised", which... [citation-needed].

Comment: @NicHartley I know that some clues are a bit far-fetched, and as you pointed out, they are not completely true.I just didn't want to leave a clue unexplained. If you have a better explanation for that clue I invite you to edit it in.

Comment: My main issue was your phrasing. I [suggested an edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/8816), but honestly, it could go either way.